# Validation in java script for @*&@ charters

Tags: regex

I want to do validation in javascript. if the string contains @*&@ charters.

```
<div style="text-align:center;"><input type="submit" value="Generate MDL" align="top" style="width: 120px;" ONCLICK="gt_nextPage();"></div></td>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function gt_nextPage() {
        var e=document.getElementById("getNumber");
        var val=e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        window.location.replace("GenerateMDL?value="+val);
    }

</script>
```

I want to check If **var val contains @*&@ characters**..? if yes give an alert message.

Thank You.

Comment: have a look at http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re.shtml

Comment: separate characters or this string `@*&@`??

Answer (score 0):

Try this (match lines containing any of the characters) :

```
var val=e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var regex = new RegExp("[@&\*]");
var res = regex.test(val);
if (res == true) { 
  alert("Found")
}
```

If you want to match characters that follow each other, replace regex line with :

```
var regex = new RegExp("@&\*");
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you want if `@`, `&` and `*` all of them to be present in your string. You have to use `look ahead` for this

```
var val = "abcd123&@*";
var reg = /(?=.*&)(?=.*@)(?=.*\*)/;

if (reg.test(val)) {
    alert("Found")
} else {
    alert("Not Found")
}
```

**[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jjdqdooq/)**

If you want any of `@`, `&` or `*`, then change the regex to

```
var reg = /[&@\*]/;
```

**[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/opv6ggo1/)**

If you want the exact string `@*&@` to be matched, then change the regex to

```
var reg = /@\*&@/;
```

**[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qfw0wxvb/)**